# Is time stamping enabled by default when using codesign utility on a mac?

Tags: macos, timestamp, codesign, code-signing-certificate

I am using the codesign utility to sign files on mac. The command is :
`codesign --sign <IDENTITY> --keychain <KEYCHAIN_PATH>`

When I verify my signed payload, I see the following fields:

```
Format=Mach-O thin (x86_64)
Hash type=sha256 size=32
CandidateCDHash sha256=
Hash choices=
CDHash=
Signature size=
Authority=Developer ID Application: <Signing Identity>
Authority=Developer ID Certification Authority
Authority=Apple Root CA
**Timestamp=May 6, 2020 at 1:39:04 AM**
Info.plist=
TeamIdentifier=
Sealed Resources=none
```

Does this mean that the payload is timestamped by default? I also read the technical note from Apple and it states the following under certificate validity:

*Developer ID signatures carry cryptographic timestamps by default. Signatures with cryptographic timestamps are validated against the signing time, and signatures made with expired (at signing time) certificates are invalid. The previous discussion still applies to Developer ID signatures without secure timestamps.*

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2206/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007919-CH1-TNTAG7

Do I need to do anything specific to make sure that timestamping is enabled? Or is it ON by default?

Answer (score 2):

From https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/notarizing_macos_software_before_distribution/resolving_common_notarization_issues

> By default, Xcode doesn’t include a secure timestamp as part of the
>   app’s code signature during the build process. Instead, it adds a
>   secure timestamp only during the archive (as of Xcode 10.2) and export
>   workflows.

Your signature suggests your case was the implicit latter one. You can explicitly enable secure timestamp during code signing with:

```
codesign --timestamp --sign <IDENTITY> --keychain <KEYCHAIN_PATH>
```

Comment: Thank you. I have included the explicit timestamp flag to include it in all my signatures.